# Package re-installed "startup packages configure"

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I have a need to install *customized kernel package* set (the usual `linux-modules-<ver>.deb`, `linux-modules-extra-<ver>.deb`, `linux-headers-<ver>.deb`, `linux-image-<ver>.deb`...). I install it on Ubuntu Bionic (`18.04.6`). It installs and things look normal, but once I reboot the VM, I see that the packages from upstream would have got installed (overwriting mine)!!
I see in `/var/log/dpkg.log`, logs like:

`startup archives unpack`

...

`startup packages configure`

I thought that this could have been *cached* and tried to clear `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but still the packages are overridden! Also, before a reboot, when I checked all the packages were in `ii` state, so its not like any of them were in bad state and needed a re-install!

I am not sure why this is happening! Can anyone throw some light on this *startup package* install please? I just want to make sure that my customized packages override the ones from upstream.

Comment: Installing a different kernel version, customized or not is irrelevant, does not uninstall any other versions. When you reboot are you choosing to boot that specific version?

Comment: Yes, I choose to boot the specific version and it does, the problem is at startup (as seen from dpkg logs) the upstream kernel packages are installed again, overwriting the existing packages!